# Recently created SQL in Azure VM backup item is not shown

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup, azureportal

I have a VM in Azure with SQL server (web edition) on it. I want to set up "SQL in Azure VM backup" for my databases. To do so, I created a Recovery Service Vault in the same region as my VPS is, and then went throught the process of creating a "SQL in Azure VM" backup items; i.e., discovered SQL instance, discovered databases and then setting up the policy. However, I think (not sure) I forgot to press the "Enable Backup" button at the end.

Now, I cannot see that backup item in the list of my back up items. I tried to create another "SQL in Azure VM" backup, but it does not allow me to select that instance of SQL server as it recognises it has been already associated to a backup item (see pics below)!

[Image 1: No backup apears here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVrPC.png)

[Image 2: The instance is already used and cannot be selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP3JB.png)

Comment: You might try using the Azure CLI to see if this is an issue with the Azure portal. Also, Azure support is usually pretty helpful.

Comment: How long has it been since the backup was originally configured?  Has the initial backup finished?

Comment: @MikeOryszak it has been for 12 hours.